# How can use File Spec in an API Call in Jfrog

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I have a question about how to use File Sepc in an API Call in JFrog.

I used Jenkins Artifactory Plugin to upload or download artifacts to JFrog, I try to rewrite the function using JFrog API (GET/PUT) to do the same thing.

but I have now a problem, for some artifacts I used file Spec to set some properties and finally I upload this file spec.

```
 "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "${file}",
      "target": "${target}" """
    if (runID) {
        uploadSpec += """,
            "props": "artifactId=${runID}"
        """
    }
uploadSpec += """      
    }
 ]
```

as you can see this artifactId.

in this case when I use JFrog API to upload artifacts how should I set properties?

```
sh """
            curl  -sSf -u user:pw -X PUT -T ${zipFile} 'https://${config.artifactory.name}.xxxx:443/artifactory/${path}'
        """
```

How can I call put api and set `"props": "artifactId=${runID}"`

any solutions??

Answer (score 0):

First - if you can use the JFrog CLI - you should use it, because it makes it simpler and provides some advanced features out-of-the-box, such as batch parallel uploads/downloads, file-specs, attaching properties, build-info, authentication, etc.

If you still want to use the Artifactory API directly for setting properties, which is indeed a viable good option, you can do one of the following:

1. Add the properties as **matrix parameters** as part of the [upload (deploy)](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+Properties+in+Deployment+and+Resolution) API call.
   In your case, it should be something like:

   ```
   sh """
     curl -sSf -u user:pw -X PUT -T ${zipFile} 'https://${config.artifactory.name}.xxxx:443/artifactory/${path};artifactId=${runID}'
   """
   ```

   Note the `;key=value` in the end of the URL.
2. Do a second call, after the upload, to **set the item properties**.
   In your case, it should be something like:
   Using the [set item properties](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-SetItemProperties) API -

   ```
   sh """
     curl -sSf -u user:pw -X PUT 'https://${config.artifactory.name}.xxxx:443/artifactory/api/storage/${path}?properties=artifactId=${runID}'
   """
   ```

   or, using the [update item properties](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-UpdateItemProperties) API-

   ```
   sh """
     curl -sSf -u user:pw -X PATCH 'https://${config.artifactory.name}.xxxx:443/artifactory/api/metadata/${path}' -d '{ "props": { "artifactId" : "${runID}" } }'
   """
   ```

For more information, see:

- [Working with JFrog Properties](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Working+with+JFrog+Properties)
- [Using Properties in Deployment and Resolution](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+Properties+in+Deployment+and+Resolution)
- Artifactory REST API - [Item Properties](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ItemProperties)